# show that Row(A) is perpendicular to Null(A)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Hi can you please help me check my work

Question: Prove that if A is a m x n matrix, vector x is an element of Row(A) and vector y is an element of Null(A), then vector x is perpendicular to y.

Attempt: since A is an m x n matrix, then A^T = n x m.
let A^T = [w1, w2, ... , wn], since x is an element of A^T ,

then x = [a1w1,a2w2, ... , anwn].

this is where i stopped. can you guys please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\DeclareMathOperator{Row}{Row}\Row(A)=\DeclareMathOperator{Col}{Col}\Col(A^\top)$. Consequently every element of $\Row(A)$ is of the form $A^\top\vec x$. Also note that $\vec y\in\DeclareMathOperator{Null}{Null}\Null(A)$ if and only if $A\vec y=\vec0$.

Now, note that $A^\top\vec x\in\Row(A)$ and $\vec y\in\Null(A)$ implies
$$
\left\langle A^\top\vec x,\vec y\right\rangle
= (A^\top\vec x)^\top\vec y=\vec x^\top A\vec y=\vec x^\top\vec 0=\vec 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. So, the rows of $A$ are $w_1^\top,\ldots,w_n^\top$, and you have written $x = a_1 w_1 + \cdots + a_n w_n$ since $x \in \operatorname{Row}(A)$.

Since $y \in \operatorname{Null}(A)$, we have $Ay=0$. If you write this equation component-wise, it is $w_i^\top y = 0$ for each $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Now, can you show $x^\top y = 0$?

Comment: i have a problem showing that